# equality of two sums

Tags: summation, arithmetic

Is $\sum _{t=1}^m \sum _{k=t}^m (a_{k+1}-a_k)b_t$ equal to $\sum _{k=1}^m \sum _{t=1}^k (a_{k+1}-a_k)b_t$?

If not, then how to derive equations for temporal difference algorithm in machine learning: page 14 at the end, and page 15 equation (3).

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/papers/sutton-88.pdf

It seems like an error?

Comment: By default, those are not the same

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be an error in this paper.

Comment: It is possible that with some special assumptions about $a_k$ that this equality may hold, although this does not hold in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^m\sum_{k=t}^m(a_{k+1}-a_k)b_t & =\sum_{t=1}^m((a_{t+1}-a_t)b_t+(a_{t+2}-a_{t+1})b_t+\cdots+(a_{m+1}-a_m))b_t\\
& =(a_2-a_1)b_1+(a_3-a_2)(b_1+b_2)+\cdots+(a_{m+1}-a_m)(b_1+\cdots+b_m)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{t=1}^k(a_{k+1}-a_k)b_t.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, I take it back. It seems that equality holds! Thank you for clarification!

Comment: When dealing with these double summations, reversing their order is a common technique. :)